# Queries becoming slow on Solr. What are my options?

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine, solr4

I have single Solr instance running on server. The number of documents in this instance has reached to a point where the queries are becoming slow. What are my options?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

Comment: I assume you have already tried adding more memory and CPU. Also how many docs. If I had a dime for every performance questions with out specifics.... Add Details. Details.

Comment: the question is not specific, please post : index size, number of documents, hardware configuration, make sure whether it is search or some other module of the application that's getting slow.